# How do I update a nested option?

Tags: wp-cli, options

I use this command to get values of ez-toc-settings->auto_insert_post_types

```
wp eval "print_r(get_option('ez-toc-settings')['auto_insert_post_types']);"
```

and this prints out the correct values:

```
Array
(
    [post] => post
    [page] => page
)
```

Now, I try to modify that so I have only "post" value
I tried with:

```
wp eval "update_option('ez-toc-settings auto_insert_post_types', array('post'));"
```

Infact I have no idea on **how to update a key value within a nested option**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`wp option`](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/option/) does all you need. See [`wp option patch`](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/option/patch/) in particular.

> Updates a nested value in an option.

---

Get a nested option value:

```
$ wp option pluck ez-toc-settings auto_insert_post_types
```

Set a nested option value (with an array):

```
$ wp option patch update ez-toc-settings auto_insert_post_types '{"post":"post"}' --format=json
```