# How to add an array to a command "wp config set"?

Tags: wp-cli

you need to add a constant when building a docker file wp-config.php

```
define( 'AS3CF_SETTINGS', serialize( array(
'provider' => 'aws',
'access-key-id' => '*****',
'secret-access-key' => '****',
```

tried using command - wp config set AS3CF_SETTINGS [' "asd" => "asd", "dsa" => "dsa"'], it passes the string(

please tell me is it possible to transfer this as an array?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update an 'array' option using wp-cli](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/267245/how-to-update-an-array-option-using-wp-cli)

Comment: With `--format=json` for example: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/345118/30597